# HTML/Javascript - checkValidity() doesn't show where is required

Tags: javascript, html

New into HTML and JS. I have been trying to figure out why I am not getting any notification while I am not entering any Name in a field. a quick video of how it is looking currently:[VIDEO of entering name](https://i.gyazo.com/fd2cb5f956af6e826c51171b7f5fdfde.mp4)

My code is looking

HTML:

```
  <!-- ================ form start ================= --> 
  <form class="form-search form-search-position">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm gutters-19">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="FormControlSelect1">Fullständiga namn</label>
            <input class="form-control" required id="namn" type="text" placeholder="Skriv in för- och efternamn..">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm gutters-19">
          <div class="form-group">
            <button class="button button-form" id="toggle" onsubmit="return false;" onclick="myFunction()" type="button">Beställning</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <!-- ================ form end ================= -->
```

JS:

```
<script>

  function myFunction() {

    var inpObj = document.getElementById("namn");
    if (!inpObj.checkValidity()) { /** Kollar ifall namnet input är skriven **/
      document.getElementById("toggle").innerHTML = inpObj.validationMessage;
    } else {
      var data = {'namn': namn.value}

      var json = JSON.stringify(data) /** Konventera till JSON **/

      let req = new XMLHttpRequest();

      req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {

          if (this.status == 200) { /** Kollar ifall request response är 200 = OK **/
            console.log("Response is looking good! [" + this.status + "]");

          } else { /** Om det är inte OK. Skicka meddelande till användaren.  **/
            console.log("Response is bad! [" + this.status + "] - Check if the server is on and connected!");
            document.getElementById("toggle").innerHTML = "Gick ej att beställa!";
            document.getElementById("toggle").disabled = true;
          }
        }
      };

      req.open("post", "https://localhost:44363/api/values"); 
      req.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
      req.send(json);
      document.getElementById("toggle").innerHTML = "Tack för beställning";
      document.getElementById("toggle").disabled = true;

      setTimeout(function(){
       window.location.reload(1);
     }, 5000);

    } 
  } 

</script>
```

```js
function myFunction() {

  var inpObj = document.getElementById("namn");
  if (!inpObj.checkValidity()) { /** Kollar ifall namnet input är skriven **/
    document.getElementById("toggle").innerHTML = inpObj.validationMessage;
  } else {
    var data = {
      'namn': namn.value
    }

    var json = JSON.stringify(data) /** Konventera till JSON **/

    let req = new XMLHttpRequest();

    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4) {

        if (this.status == 200) { /** Kollar ifall request response är 200 = OK **/
          console.log("Response is looking good! [" + this.status + "]");

        } else { /** Om det är inte OK. Skicka meddelande till användaren.  **/
          console.log("Response is bad! [" + this.status + "] - Check if the server is on and connected!");
          document.getElementById("toggle").innerHTML = "Gick ej att beställa!";
          document.getElementById("toggle").disabled = true;
        }
      }
    };

    req.open("post", "https://localhost:44363/api/values");
    req.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    req.send(json);
    document.getElementById("toggle").innerHTML = "Tack för beställning";
    document.getElementById("toggle").disabled = true;

    setTimeout(function() {
      window.location.reload(1);
    }, 5000);

  }
}
```

```html
<!-- ================ form start ================= -->
<form class="form-search form-search-position">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm gutters-19">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="FormControlSelect1">Fullständiga namn</label>
          <input class="form-control" required id="namn" type="text" placeholder="Skriv in för- och efternamn..">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm gutters-19">
        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="button button-form" id="toggle" onsubmit="return false;" onclick="myFunction()" type="button">Beställning</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<!-- ================ form end ================= -->
```

Basically the issue is that whenever I do not enter any name, it is supposed to either it shows a red "background" on the border or just a small popout to tell the user that it is required to enter a Name here.

How can I do that?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_validation_check 
See this examle

Comment: @Kondal Before it used to do something like this [link](https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/70c542cd79a38cc22acfaad71e147dd02629bd99/7ffcd/images/posts/2012-08-05/chrome.png) but now it doesn't do it anymore. Is it possible to get something like that?

Comment: We have to show error because user able to understand

https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_validation_rangeUnderflow

Comment: Right! How would I possible do that! Would appreciate the help :)

Comment: Check above example replace INPUT OK to "" field is required

Comment: The example just does it through an <p> though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are checking the validity of the name input object in the following if statement:

```
  var inpObj = document.getElementById("namn");
  if (!inpObj.checkValidity()) { /** Kollar ifall namnet input är skriven **/
    document.getElementById("toggle").innerHTML = inpObj.validationMessage;
  } else {
    var data = {
      'namn': namn.value
    }
  }
```

You set submit button text to the validation message. What you wanna do is take your input object (inpObj) and change the background color. This can be done as follows:

```
  var inpObj = document.getElementById("namn");
  if (!inpObj.checkValidity()) { /** Kollar ifall namnet input är skriven **/
    inpObj.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  } else {
    var data = {
      'namn': namn.value;
    }
    inpObj.style.backgroundColor = "none";
 }
```

For the display of an error message you want to insert a  element below the input element that has a standard display set to none as below:

```
    <input class="form-control" required id="namn" type="text" placeholder="Skriv in för- och efternamn..">
    <div id="error-message" style="display:none">Please fill in your name</div>
```

You can than toggle the display as needed by doing the following in your function:

```
var errorMessage = document.getElementById("error-message");
errorMessage.style.display = "block";
```

You can find a snippet below:

```js
function myFunction() {

  var inpObj = document.getElementById("namn");
  if (!inpObj.checkValidity()) { /** Kollar ifall namnet input är skriven **/
    inpObj.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    var errorMessage = document.getElementById("error-message");
    errorMessage.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    inpObj.style.backgroundColor = "none";
    var errorMessage = document.getElementById("error-message");
    errorMessage.style.display = "none";
    var data = {
      'namn': namn.value
    }

    var json = JSON.stringify(data) /** Konventera till JSON **/

    let req = new XMLHttpRequest();

    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4) {

        if (this.status == 200) { /** Kollar ifall request response är 200 = OK **/
          console.log("Response is looking good! [" + this.status + "]");

        } else { /** Om det är inte OK. Skicka meddelande till användaren.  **/
          console.log("Response is bad! [" + this.status + "] - Check if the server is on and connected!");
          document.getElementById("toggle").innerHTML = "Gick ej att beställa!";
          document.getElementById("toggle").disabled = true;
        }
      }
    };

    req.open("post", "https://localhost:44363/api/values");
    req.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    req.send(json);
    document.getElementById("toggle").innerHTML = "Tack för beställning";
    document.getElementById("toggle").disabled = true;

    setTimeout(function() {
      window.location.reload(1);
    }, 5000);

  }
}
```

```html
<!-- ================ form start ================= --> 
  <form class="form-search form-search-position">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm gutters-19">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="FormControlSelect1">Fullständiga namn</label>
            <input class="form-control" required id="namn" type="text" placeholder="Skriv in för- och efternamn..">
            <div id="error-message" style="display:none">Please fill in your name</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm gutters-19">
          <div class="form-group">
            <button class="button button-form" id="toggle" onsubmit="return false;" onclick="myFunction()" type="button">Beställning</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <!-- ================ form end ================= -->
```

Comment: Ohhh! Now I do understand what you mean! Thats actually alot cooler than I expected and not that harder either now when you think about it. Apprecaite it but is it possible to change back the backgroundcolor if it is "valid"? and also remove the "Please fill in" when it is entered AFTER a failure of not entering?

Comment: I created a new fiddle here: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dp5ax6ct/2/). This fiddle will do what you describe above. In this fiddle I make use of an eventlistener, I explained everything a bit in comments.